# Partial Formula Replacement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace part of a formula in a cell.

I have an InputBox to specify a number, and a replace function to replace the value. (Just for good measure, I made the range include the cell with the formula and a few blank cells around it.)

My macro fills the blank cells with the new value, but does not replace needed value in Excel.

I want the unchanged value to be XXXX and to allow the user to input their own value which would correspond with the Excel file to retrieve data from.

```vb
Sub Replace_XXXX_and_YYYY() 

SN1 = InputBox("Enter 1st Serial Number") 

SN2 = InputBox("Enter 2nd Serial Number") 

Range("B9:B11").Replace What:=XXXX, Replacement:=SN1 

Range("B9:B11").Replace What:=YYYY, Replacement:=SN2 

End Sub
```

Comment: Are `XXXX` and `YYYY` variables (or constants) that you have declared somewhere? Or did you simply missed the quotes (`"XXXX"`) to really replace the string `XXXX` (and also missed to use Option Explicit)?

Comment: The XXXX and YYYY are place holders so that the formula would change XXXX and YYYY into the entered serial numbers and make the formula find the corresponding documents.

Comment: No, I am asking what `XXXX` in your VBA code is? I would suggest you put the statement  `Option Explicit` at the top of your code and compile it.

Comment: The following formula is a part of the formula i am trying to change with the vba code. I cannot put the whole formula as i have only so many characters I can input here.    =IF(ROUND(MAX('[PN 4020-5 - SN XXXX.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$67,'[PN 4020-5 - SN XXXX.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$78,'[PN 4020-5 - SN XXXX.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$89,'[PN 4020-5 - SN XXXX.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$100,'[PN 4020-5 - SN XXXX.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$111),4)>ROUND(MAX('[PN 4020-5 - SN YYYY.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$67,'[PN 4020-5 - SN YYYY.xlsx]

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in my first comment: You probably want to replace the `"XXXX"` of the formula with something.

You need to put quotes around the `"XXXX"` so VBA (not Excel) knows that you want to deal with a string - else it will look for a variable (or function) named `XXXX`. And as you likely have not defined (and assigned) such variable and you don't have `Option Explicit` set, VBA will create a variable on the fly. So `What` will get an empty string as parameter and the replace does nothing.

```
Range("B9:B11").Replace What:="XXXX", Replacement:=SN1
```